# differences between all the FFTs?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Wikipedia lists a lot of FFT algorithms:

Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm, Prime-factor FFT algorithm, Bruun's FFT algorithm, Rader's FFT algorithm, and Bluestein's FFT algorithm

What are the pros and cons of each algorithms?
And which one do you prefer?

Comment: After carefully considering our FAQ, I can see that your question is, in fact, *on topic* since you seem to be asking about the *algorithms* rather than their *applications*.  Still, it's unclear what "pros and cons" you're looking for specifically: computational expense, parallelizability, ease of implementation,...?  You should really try to narrow the focus of your question to a specific criterion of comparison. Otherwise, i'd have to agree with the comments made [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8977/what-are-the-differences-between-the-various-fft-algorithms).

Comment: 'computational expense, parallelizability, ease of implementation,' all of them?

Comment: The scope of this question is too broad because its scope is a review article, rather than something that could be answered relatively succinctly, which is why it's a tough question to answer well, and why the DSP mods closed your question and gave you links to review articles.

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ... **overly broad** ... and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Comment: Hi, user8005, Would you consider rewording the question to ask for _computational expense_ & _parallelizability_ of these algorithms?